# Custom error page in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to show the custom error page when something goes wrong in silverlight application like in asp.net. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to subscribe on unhandled exception in the main page of the silverlight application and then route the call to custom error page, where you could show the appropritate error message.

Comment: In my case it's Prism, so the container(host) will be subscribing & unhandled exception event in App.Xaml.cs will be the publisher? Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Yes. if it is the master one to trap the unhandled exception then yes.

Comment: Thanks. I found alternative solution to show the ErrorWindow.Create with policy to show stacktrace only when it is local or debug mode.